# How to share a large amount of data between activities?

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` that fetches a large-ish amount of data from a web server using Retrofit. This data is shown in a recycler view.

Now, I want to have another activity which works on the exact same data set. What's the most efficient way to do this? Earlier I have done this using a static `Controller` that keeps track of the data, but I keep hearing a lot of critique about static containers like that. Passing the data in the intents is not optimal, since the data is rather complicated and there's so much of it.

Optimally, I'd like to be able to modify the data set in either of the activities so that the changes are reflected to the other activity as well.

Comment: Dont you think it would just be better to use a DB for this?. Something fast such as SnappyDB. Otherwise you might use static variables, but those are bad. Passing the list will be easy by either using Serialization or Parceable, but those can turn out to be a burden on a large data set

Comment: @Smashing The data is not supposed to be persistent - it's there only for the lifetime of the app. The data is already in the memory, so the fastest way should be to just pass it to the second activity.

Comment: pass the data as `ArrayList<>` to another activity and get the data using `getIntent().getSerializableExtra` using type-casting according the type of `ArrayList<>` you passed

Comment: so if you want to provide a content to different clients use a custom `CuntentProvider`, override its `query` method and use `CursorLoader` to get the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider 2 options (depending on the amount of data you would like to share, and the type of devices your app is suppose to run on)

1. You can extended the application class to include global data between your activities. You can read more about it here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state
2. You can use persistence storage (i.e. sqlite/file).

There are trade-offs for each approach. And which one will suit you best depends on your specific setup.